Divi Builder Theme changing logos in the customized footer in Wordpress
The website uses a child theme of the Divi Builder Theme - Divi Version: 4.25.1
I need to change 3 logos in the footer of a website. The link is below.
https://www.slowdown-travemuende.de/de/
It took me 3 days to discover that the footer created on the website is customized.
Here is the excerpt of the PHP code within the functions.php file in the child theme, referring to the creation of the customized footer.
  function sd_add_custom_footer() {
    $section = do_shortcode('[et_pb_section test global_module="133"][/et_pb_section]');
    echo '<div id="custom-footer" class="custom-footer">' . $section . '</div>';
  }
  add_action('et_after_main_content', 'sd_add_custom_footer');

Below is the screenshot of the footer on the website.

Important Info. It is not possible to change or change the footer logo using the standard path Divi > Theme customizer > Footer> Layout> Widget > ElementeFooter > MenüFooter > bottom footer bar
The custom footer session, created through the function in the functions.php file, does not allow editing or make any visual change to the logos.
Please where can I find the file that must be changed, or the session where the shortcode was inserted as described in the function function
sd_add_custom_footer() {
There is no plugin installed on the website specifically for inserting and using shortcodes.
so I can change the 3 logos? All help is very valuable! I'm already desperate!!

What's happening here is that the PHP code is using Divi's global module mechanism to load and display an item from the Divi Library. The library item has the id 133.
To find it, go into the Divi Library at:
WP Dashboard > Divi > Divi Library

Hopefully it's obvious which of the items on that page is the one with your logos. If not, then hover over the edit link for each item and look for "post=133" in the URL.
Once found, you should be able to open up and edit the layout as you would any regular Divi layout. It looks like the logos are added using text modules.

Buddy, Thank you for the help. In the Divi Library there are 78 pages. It means there is a pagination with 4 sessions. The footer page with the item 133 is the last one :  )

It's always the way! Glad you found it, @PaulodoPorto :)
